# How to get a percentage of a height from a VH calc?

Tags: css, calc

I'm trying to set an element height which is 70% of a calc which works out 100vh minus a header height.

element height: calc((100vh - 110px(*fixed header height*) - 30%)

so if the view height was 900px the element should equal **553px** -> calc((900px - 110px) / 100 * 70))

However my calc doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try like this: i think if you use porcentage is better

calc(100% - 110px - 30%)

Answer (score 3):

why not use calc(70vh - 110px) ?

If you want 100vh-110px - 30% of direct parent height .... amm  better switch to JavaScript. The % is from the parent dimension. If the dimension can not be determined- calculation fails.

Anyway.. in order for this to work- you have to fix the height of the parent container. If the body is the parent- you have to fix the height of the body and then try to perform the calc.

The calc can work with the width of the body, like calc(100vw - 110px - 24%) , but this is because the width is usually fixed/restricted.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}

header {
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #333;
}

main {
  height: calc((100vh - 110px) * .7);
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need:

`height: calc((100vh - "fixed height) *.7);`

```css
header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

main {
  height: calc((100vh - 100px) *.7);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you know the priority is division. So you must put them in braces like this. You must tell us what is the unit of the *30* cause it wont subtract to a unitless number. `px vh ...`

```css
/*element height: calc((100vh - 110px(fixed header height) - 30%)*/
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: orange
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc((100vh - 110px) - 30vh);
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section><section>
```